# AttributeError when serializing relationship with 'through' table

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make **Django Rest Framework** return me a to-many relationship constructed with `through` keyword. However, I'm getting an error and have no idea what's wrong.

The error I'm getting is:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `step_number` on serializer `StepInfoSerializer`. The serializer field
>   might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
>   `Step` instance. Original exception text was: 'Step' object has no
>   attribute 'step_number'.

Here is my model:

```
class Step(BaseModel):

    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

class StepInfo(BaseModel):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe')
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step)
    step_number = models.IntegerField()

class Recipe(BaseModel):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    steps = models.ManyToManyField(Step, through='StepInfo')
```

And implementation of serializers:

```
class StepInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    description = serializers.CharField(source="step.description")

    class Meta:
        model = StepInfo
        fields = ('id',
                  'step_number',
                  'description')


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    steps = StepInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id',
                  'steps')
```

Can anyone cast some light on this problem? I'd really appreciate!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way to change that is change the source of your steps in `RecipeSerializer`

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    steps = StepInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='stepinfo_set')
```

now I will make an explanation about that.

first, only in the Django world.

for example, `rec` is an instance object of `Recipe` Model.

Get the difference of the two statement.

```
rec.steps.all()
rec.stepinfo_set.all()
```

`rec.steps.all()` will returns an array of `Step` object instance, make sure it's the **target model of ManyToManyField**, not the **through** model.

if you want to access **through** model, you need to visit from the `related_name` of the `ForeignKey` refer to current model in the Through Model (`StepInfo` Model).

later, I will add an example with related_name.

since in your `StepInfo` does not specify the `related_name`, so django will automatically give you a default related_name `stepinfo_set`. (this name is that one in the first snippet).

so will return back to how to get through instances. just `rec.setpinfo_set.all()`.

All right, in the end, I suggest you add the related_name to your ForeignKey in your Through Models.

```
class StepInfo(BaseModel):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', related_name='stepinfos')
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, related_name='stepinfos')
    step_number = models.IntegerField()

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    steps = StepInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='stepinfos')
```

Comment: This is one of the best answers I ever got on Stack Overflow. I learnt a lot. Thanks!